# Difference between calculation of from_bytes vs. unpack

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, unpack, bytestream

I've been trying to figure out why this byte array leads to different results using two approaches:

```py
print(msg[16:20])
>>> b'\xe4\x86\xaaU'
msg[16:20].hex()
>>> e486aa55
print(int.from_bytes(msg[16:20], byteorder='big', signed='False'))
>>> -460936619
print(unpack_from('!I', msg, offset=16)[0])
>>> 3834030677
print(unpack('!I', msg[16:20])[0])
>>> 3834030677
```

How is it, that using the builtin `from_bytes()` function is calculating a wrong result? I've recalculated it on my own (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509434) and the result should be similar to the one using `unpack()`

```
228*256^3+134*256^2+170*256^1+85+256^0 = 3834030677
```

Hope to find my fault / wrong thinking with your guys help - thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `signed = False` instead of `signed = 'False'`.

`'False'` is a string and since it's non-empty, it is treated as a truthy value. Therefore, the number gets signed.

```python
k = b'\xe4\x86\xaaU'

# UNSIGNED
print(int.from_bytes(k, byteorder = 'big', signed = False))

# SIGNED
print(int.from_bytes(k, byteorder = 'big', signed = True))
print(int.from_bytes(k, byteorder = 'big', signed = 'False'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1vBViFJPaYi1SSmwsIspiIxMVSdi0tZIdQv2NPdz9WFq6AoM69EA4j10oryc@OTKktSizWydRRAjPyilNQioAHqSZnp6joKxZnpeakpQL5bYk5xqqYmyBwKTAkpKgUZQo5WdbAL1DU1//8HAA)

Comment: Duh.. pretty obvious, but still I haven't seen it - thanks a lot for the quick response!